# How can i load dropdown values dynamically in acumatica for each row with different dropdown values?

Tags: acumatica

Example:

As per the Below screenshot, i have to combine below two grids into one grid and the first grid(query list) will display as it is and the second grid values should show as drop down for the respective query.

[Samplegridsimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnkZ2.png)

when i tried to use field selecting event, it is loading all vales from second grid but i need only 3 values for fuel type value and for others different drop down.

can anyone suggest how to get only particular values in the drop down.

```
protected virtual void KNRWTAXQueries_Response_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        KNRWTAXQueries doc = e.Row as KNRWTAXQueries;
        if (doc == null) return;
        List<string> Responsevalues = new List<string>();
        List<string> ResponseLables = new List<string>();
        if (QueryList.Current != null)
        {
            if (Base.Transactions.Current != null)
            {
                foreach (KNRWTAXQueries queries in PXSelect<KNRWTAXQueries, Where<KNRWTAXQueries.nonStockItemID, Equal<Required<APTran.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, doc.NonStockItemID))
                {
                    foreach (KNRWTAXResponse response in PXSelect<KNRWTAXResponse, Where<KNRWTAXResponse.tAXQueID, Equal<Required<KNRWTAXResponse.tAXQueID>>>>.
                    Select(Base, queries.Taxqueid))
                    {
                        Responsevalues.Add(response.Response);
                        ResponseLables.Add(response.Response);
                        e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, 255, true, typeof(KNRWTAXQueries.response).Name, false, 1, string.Empty, Responsevalues.ToArray(),
                ResponseLables.ToArray(), true, null);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // ((PXStringState)e.ReturnState).MultiSelect = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use RowSelected event of the row to set the list. No need to use FieldSelecting (however you can use field selecting too)
2. You should use  PXStringListAttribute.SetList method to set new list instead of using string state
3. You should set MatrixMode=true in the aspx grid row so that list is recreated for each row (oterwise the list will be the same for all rows)

`<px:PXGridColumn DataField="OrigTranType" Type="DropDownList" MatrixMode="true" />`